# How come my float value is always returning 0 for all entries in postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

Ive been wanting to incorporate a full-text search in to my website but getting the ranking of return results from a search is holding me up. The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-controls.html) show how to do it but I keep getting 0 as a result for all my post entries selected.

```
my_app_development=# SELECT content, ts_rank(to_tsvector('microposts.content'), query) 
AS rank FROM microposts, to_tsquery('sit') query WHERE microposts.content @@ query 
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10;
                      content                      | rank
---------------------------------------------------+------
 Dolorem sed omnis iusto sit inventore quia dolor. |    0
 Dolorem sed omnis iusto sit inventore quia dolor. |    0
 Dolorem sed omnis iusto sit inventore quia dolor. |    0
 Dolorem sed omnis iusto sit inventore quia dolor. |    0
 Dolorem sed omnis iusto sit inventore quia dolor. |    0
 Vel sit ut qui aperiam aut sunt.                  |    0
 Vel sit ut qui aperiam aut sunt.                  |    0
 Vel sit ut qui aperiam aut sunt.                  |    0
 Vel sit ut qui aperiam aut sunt.                  |    0
 Dolorem sed omnis iusto sit inventore quia dolor. |    0
 (10 rows)
```

Is this expected behavior and if so what am I doing wrong.

Cheers.

Lee.

Comment: maybe you meant `ts_rank(to_tsvector(content),query)` instead?..

Comment: hmm, that is just returning 0.1 for all items now.

Comment: Ok it seems to be working now. i will post my code up but i did something different plus I think searching what I was `sit` was not valid for some reason, but searching two words together works.

Comment: please - don't. if your original question is answered accept or neglect answer - dont modify post to have DIFFERENT question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking rate for same phrase in every row `to_tsvector('microposts.content')`, instead you should use `ts_rank(to_tsvector(content),query)`

also, I assume you should define language for accurate results:

```
SELECT content, ts_rank(to_tsvector('latin',content), query) 
AS rank FROM microposts, to_tsquery('latin','sit') query WHERE microposts.content @@ query 
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10;
```

also I'm not sure whether `sit` is not a stop word to be ignored at all...

Comment: `ERROR:  text search configuration "latin" does not exist
LINE 2: AS rank FROM microposts, to_tsquery('latin','sit') query WHE...` I get what your saying but it says it does not exist plus, "sit" is a english word so you think it would still be able to do ranking even though it is in latin?

Comment: I switched your answer up to `'spanish'` and I got a set of results back but they all returned `0.06079..`, this was with a few different ways so Iam not sure why it doesnt work, but if I search a english worded post I get correct results with modified code.

Comment: BTW that was the answer `ts_rank(to_tsvector(content),query)` I am not sure why it didnt work for me the first time.